# what should be the format of http logs of a proxy?

Tags: logs, proxy, http, reverse-proxy, http-logging

In this specific case I am using fabio and nginx and apache http proxy that just proxies requests to destinations.

Both the "Combined Log Format" and "Common Log Format" *do not* include where to a proxy request is redirected and if the client is using http or https of the request and to which host the request wants to connect to. They also do not include the client port of the request.

Is there a standardized "proxy log format" that should be used to log such information? How do I go about adding them - on the end of common log format? or should I ignore and just come up with something of my log format?

Answer (score 1):

ISTR that a lot of proxies support [NCSA Common Log Format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Log_Format) - but this is very limited.

The format you choose really depends on what you want to with your log files. Unfortunately the User agent string in combined log format (or any other attribute which has embedded spaces) makes parsing and restructuring the log a little difficult.

Previously I just appended fields to the end of the combined log format for front-end/back-end times, origin server, protocol and cache hit - this meant I could continue using the log analyzer I already had in place. But moving the user-agent string to the end of the line would mean I could easily get a combined log format with a simple awk script.

CEF was supposed to address the shortcomings of syslog type messages - but IMHO its unnecessarily complicated and inflexible.